# How to get session user id in custome php file

Tags: ajax, sessions

```
    I want user session id in my custom ajax file named "ajax_page.php" below is code that i have placed in that file but i am not able to get object array of $user that i'hv defined as Global $user.


          <?php

               define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/taconsultant/');
                require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT.'includes/bootstrap.inc');
                require_once (DRUPAL_ROOT . 'includes/common.inc');
                require_once (DRUPAL_ROOT . 'includes/module.inc');
                require_once (DRUPAL_ROOT . 'includes/unicode.inc');
                require_once (DRUPAL_ROOT . 'includes/file.inc');
                drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
                drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

                global $user;

                $uid = $user->uid;


 if($_REQUEST['type'] && $_REQUEST['type'] == 'buy_course'){

         $cid = $_REQUEST['cid'];
         $course = taxonomy_term_load($cid);
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($user);
          exit;
         $log = db_insert('tbl_user_log')
                ->fields(array(
                        'uid' => $uid,
                        'title'=>$course->name,
                        'points'=>$course->field_payment_amount['und'][0]['value'],
                        'type'=>'-', 
                        'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                        ))->execute();

    }

        ?>

The output i got in console after print_r($user) is
  <?php  
    <pre>stdClass Object

        (
            [uid] => 0
            [hostname] => ::1
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [1] => anonymous user
                )

            [cache] => 0
        ) 
?>
```

Comment: Please don't say that this is asked before and duplicated because i didn't get exact answer that i want

Comment: What exact answer _do_ you want? What was wrong with the methods you've already tried? Providing that information is pretty much necessary if you don't want this to be closed as a duplicate. It _has_ been asked before, if you're having trouble implementing it you need to be more forthcoming with **why** you're having trouble. Any reason you're bootstrapping Drupal twice?

Comment: i am new in drupal and here i have used one custom ajax page to perform some jquery operations , so i need access of users details and also all the default function of drupal like taxonomy_term_load and all other but i dont know which files i need to include.

Comment: In that case literally everything you need to know is in the duplicate

Comment: its shows error like below <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function taxonomy_term_load() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\taconsultant
\sites\all\themes\taconsultant\theme\ajax_page.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />

Comment: please guide me if you have any realted solution. i want to access all drupal functions in that custom file.

Comment: Compare the code in the duplicate to your code - it'll be obvious what you need to change (everything above `global $user` in your current code)

Comment: no.. all other includes i have removed its just for testing currently i have this much of included files.     define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/taconsultant/');
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT.'includes/bootstrap.inc');

Comment: Please **read the answers (and comments) to the other question**. What you need to know is all there, I'm not going to repeat it all here :)

Comment: which files i have to include to access all function of drupal..?

Comment: For "all function" you would need to include all of them

Comment: Also try [`module_load_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_all/7) while you're there, that may be a handy shortcut

Comment: Thank you  Clive its working now.. i have include all needed file as you've suggested.

Comment: its working by including drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);